# Is it anorphane property?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

The prop1_id column of the alf_prop_unique_ctx table, the id column of the alf_prop_root table, and the root_prop_id column of alf_prop_link find that the values of these three columns are the same.Is it anorphane property?